# Passing 2D array to a Function in c++

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

I am Having Problem with Passing  a 2D array to a c++ Function. The function is supposed to print the value of 2D array. But getting errors.
In function `void showAttributeUsage(int)`
Invalid types for int(int)  for array subscript.
I know the problem is with the syntax in which I am passing the particular array to function but I don't know how to have this particular problem solved.
Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void showAttributeUsage(int);
int main()
{
    int qN, aN;
    cout << "Enter Number of Queries : ";
    cin >> qN;
    cout << "\nEnter Number of Attributes : ";
    cin >> aN;
    int attVal[qN][aN];
    cout << "\nEnter Attribute Usage Values" << endl;
    for(int n = 0; n < qN; n++) { //for looping in queries
        cout << "\n\n***************** COLUMN " << n + 1 << " *******************\n\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < aN; i++) {     //for looping in Attributes
LOOP1:
            cout << "Use(Q" << n + 1 << " , " << "A" << i + 1 << ") = ";
            cin >> attVal[n][i];
            cout << endl;
            if((attVal[n][i] > 1) || (attVal[n][i] < 0)) {
                cout << "\n\nTHE VALUE MUST BE 1 or 0 . Please Re-Enter The Values\n\n";
                goto LOOP1;                  //if wrong input value
            }

        }

    }
    showAttributeUsage(attVal[qN][aN]);
    cout << "\n\nYOUR ATTRIBUTE USAGE MATRIX IS\n\n";

    getch();
    return 0;

}
void showAttributeUsage(int att)
{
    int n = 0, i = 0;
    while(n != '\0') {
        while(i != '\0') {
            cout << att[n][i] << " ";
            i++;

        }
        cout << endl;
        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int attVal[qN][aN]` requires variable length Array (VLA) (compiler extension).  
You should use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: isn't there any simpler way to do that other than vectors?

Comment: `goto LOOP1;`  Why are you using `goto` here?  Why are you using `goto` at all?

Comment: `isn't there any simpler way to do that other than vectors? `  What is difficult about `std::vector`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Particular Logic* worked for me. At last found it. :-)

```
int** create2dArray(int rows, int cols) {

    int** array = new int*[rows];

    for (int row=0; row<rows; row++) {

        array[row] = new int[cols];

    }

    return array;

}



void delete2dArray(int **ar, int rows, int cols) {

    for (int row=0; row<rows; row++) {

        delete [] ar[row];

    }

    delete [] ar;

}


void loadDefault(int **ar, int rows, int cols) {

    int a = 0;

    for (int row=0; row<rows; row++) {

        for (int col=0; col<cols; col++) {

            ar[row][col] = a++;

        }

    }

}



void print(int **ar, int rows, int cols) {

    for (int row=0; row<rows; row++) {

        for (int col=0; col<cols; col++) {

            cout << " | " << ar[row][col];

        }

        cout << " | " << endl;

    }

}

int main () {

    int rows = 0;

    int cols = 0;

    cout<<"ENTER NUMBER OF ROWS:\t";cin>>rows;
    cout<<"\nENTER NUMBER OF COLUMNS:\t";cin>>cols;
    cout<<"\n\n";

    int** a = create2dArray(rows, cols);

    loadDefault(a, rows, cols);

    print(a, rows, cols);

    delete2dArray(a, rows, cols);
    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really suggest to use `std::vector` : [live example](https://ideone.com/rCkMX4)

```
void showAttributeUsage(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& att)
{
    for (std::size_t n = 0; n != att.size(); ++n) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i != att.size(); ++i) {
            cout << att[n][i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

And call it that way:

```
showAttributeUsage(attVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I see no reason why you can't use `std::vector`.

First, your code uses a non-standard C++ extension, namely `Variable Length Arrays` (VLA).  If your goal is to write standard C++ code, what you wrote is not valid standard C++.

Second, your initial attempt of passing an `int` is wrong, but if you were to use `vector`, your attempt at passing an `int` will look almost identical if you used `vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

typedef std::vector<int> IntArray;
typedef std::vector<IntArray> IntArray2D;

using namespace std;
void showAttributeUsage(const IntArray2D&);
int main()
{
   int qN, aN;
   cout << "Enter Number of Queries : ";
   cin >> qN;
   cout << "\nEnter Number of Attributes : ";
   cin >> aN;
   IntArray2D attVal(qN, IntArray(aN));
   //...  Input left out ...
   showAttributeUsage(attVal);
   return 0;
}

void showAttributeUsage(const IntArray2D& att)
{
   for_each(att.begin(), att.end(), 
            [](const IntArray& ia) {std::copy(ia.begin(), ia.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")); cout << endl;});
}
```

I left out the input part of the code.  The `vector` uses `[]` just like a regular array, so no code has to be rewritten once you declare the vector.  You can use the code given to you in the other answer by *molbdnilo* for inputing the data (without using the `goto`).

Second, just to throw it into the mix, the `showAttributeUsage` function uses the `copy` algorithm to output the information.  The `for_each` goes throw each row of the vector, calling `std::copy` for the row of elements.  If you are using a C++11 compliant compiler, the above should compile.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the function like this.

```
void array_function(int m, int n, float a[m][n])
{
      for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
          for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
              a[i][j] = 0.0;
}
```

where you pass in the dimensions of array.

Comment: That doesn't compile.

Comment: why float?how ever the type of array is int

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function). You need to use pointers or templates. Other solutions exists too.

In short do something like this:

```
template <size_t rows, size_t cols>
void showAttributeUsage(int (&array)[rows][cols])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << ": ";
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
            std::cout << array[i][j] << '\t';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `rows` and `cols` are not compile time values in OP's case... BTW, you may add `const`.

Comment: Agree. `std::vector` is the straight solution for variable inputs

Answer (score 0):

You're using a compiler extension that lets you declare arrays with a size determined at runtime.
There is no way to pass a 2D array with such dimensions to a function, since all but one dimension for an array as a function parameter must be known at compile time.

You can use fixed dimensions and use the values read as limits that you pass to the function:

```
const int max_queries = 100; 
const int max_attributes = 100;

void showAttributeUsage(int array[max_queries][max_attributes], int queries, int attributes);


int main()
{
    int attVal[max_queries][max_attributes];
    int qN = 0;
    int aN = 0;
    cout << "Enter Number of Queries (<= 100) : ";   
    cin >> qN;
    cout << "\nEnter Number of Attributes (<= 100) : ";   
    cin >> aN;

    cout << "\nEnter Attribute Usage Values" << endl;
    for (int n = 0; n < qN; n++)
    {
        cout << "\n\n***************** COLUMN " << n + 1 <<" *******************\n\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < aN; i++)
        {
            bool bad_input = true;
            while (bad_input)
            {
                bad_input = false;  // Assume that input will be correct this time.
                cout << "Use(Q" << n + 1 << " , " << "A" << i + 1 << ") = ";
                cin >> attVal[n][i];
                cout << endl;
                if (attVal[n][i] > 1 || attVal[n][i] < 0)
                { 
                    cout << "\n\nTHE VALUE MUST BE 1 or 0 . Please Re-Enter The Values\n\n";
                    bad_input = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\nYOUR ATTRIBUTE USAGE MATRIX IS\n\n";
    showAttributeUsage(attVal, qN, aN);

    getch();
    return 0;   
}

void showAttributeUsage(int att[max_queries][max_attributes], int queries, int attributes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < queries; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < attributes; j++)
        {
            cout << att[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

---

For comparison, the same program using `std::vector`, which is almost identical but with no size limitations:

```
void showAttributeUsage(vector<vector<int> > att);

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter Number of Queries (<= 100) : ";   
    cin >> qN;
    cout << "\nEnter Number of Attributes (<= 100) : ";   
    cin >> aN;

    vector<vector<int> > attVal(qN, vector<int>(aN));

    cout << "\nEnter Attribute Usage Values"<<endl;
    for (int n = 0; n < qN; n++)
    {
        cout<<"\n\n***************** COLUMN "<<n+1<<" *******************\n\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < aN; i++)
        {
            bool bad = true;
            while (bad)
            {
                bad = false;
                cout << "Use(Q" << n + 1 << " , " << "A" << i + 1 << ") = ";
                cin >> attVal[n][i];
                cout << endl;
                if (attVal[n][i] > 1 || attVal[n][i] < 0)
                { 
                    cout << "\n\nTHE VALUE MUST BE 1 or 0 . Please Re-Enter The Values\n\n";
                    bad = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\nYOUR ATTRIBUTE USAGE MATRIX IS\n\n";
    showAttributeUsage(attVal);

    getch();
    return 0;   
}

void showAttributeUsage(vector<vector<int> > att);
{
    for (int i = 0; i < att.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < att[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << att[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, in the first case, it should be `void showAttributeUsage(int (&att)[max_queries][max_attributes], int queries, int attributes)
`

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, if you want safety. I hesitate to throw the stranger syntactic incantations of the language at beginners.

Answer (score 0):

if its c++ then you can use a templete that would work with any number of dimensions

```
template<typename T>
void func(T& v)
{
    // code here
}

int main()
{
    int arr[][7] = {
        {1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
        {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
    };
    func(arr);
    char triplestring[][2][5] = {
        {
            "str1",
            "str2"
        },
        {
            "str3",
            "str4"
        }
    };
    func(triplestring);
    return 0;
}
```